# How can I connect to a SQL Server using SSMS 2016?

Tags: networking, ssms, sql-server-2016

I'm a rookie so I'm not really acquainted with how this really works. I've downloaded SQL Server 2016 and once I log onto the Management Studio, it asks me to connect to a particular server.

I've no idea what server I should connect to.  I've tried everything. Turned the firewall off, used cmd commands, (tells me that my access has been denied), registered a new server from within the studio (but nothing shows up in the `Server Name` drop-down) I'm really confused.

What server should I connect to?

[image]

Comment: `Select @@ServerName`

Comment: "once I log onto the Management Studio, it asks me to connect to a particular server"  I'm not really following this.  Either I don't know what you mean by "log onto the Management Studio" or I have never seen the dialog asking you to connect to a server.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @BaconBits I assume he's referring to the `Connect to Server` dialog box that pops up when you open any version of SSMS.

Comment: Though, something still doesn't quite make sense.  Why would you try turning the firewall off to see which SQL Server you connected to in SSMS?  It just seems like a really odd thing to try.  I'm curious - do you have a specific SQL Server you're trying to access?

Comment: I tried turning the firewall off so that it can have access to remote connections. A solution told me to do so

Comment: Most probably you have to connect to `.\sqlexpress` or `(local)\sqlexpress` (they are synonyms). If no success open Computer Management, navigate to Services, find SQL Server and read its instance name. Also make sure it is started.

Comment: @ZainabMurtaza Strange...  regardless, running `Select @@ServerName` from SSMS will tell you what server you're connected to.  You can also visibly see all of the servers you're connected to from the `Object Explorer` pane.

Comment: I'm not connected to any server. I want to connect to a server. I don't know how to since I can't determine which one I'm on. I've tried everything. Alex's reply as well. Nothing seems to be working. :/

Comment: @ZainabMurtaza That is a completely different question from what you asked...

Comment: Open Server Name dropdown  in connect to dialog, select "Browse for more..." to see available (local and network) sql servers.

Comment: I've updated the wording of your question.  You were asking a completely different question before.  If you feel my edit is not correct, please change it back.

Comment: Browse for more comes up with no results

Comment: I feel like I'm not connected to any server or something but that's just stupid

Comment: Make sure the server you installed (?) is running.

Comment: No server installed- I'm trying, but it isn't working

Comment: Is the service running?  Open SQL Server Configuration Manager (it's in Computer Management under Services and Applications) and make sure that the service is runnning.

Comment: This might seem really odd but the service isn't even appearing there. I have everything installed but the service dialogue isn't even there.

Comment: Sounds to me like your installation is borked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the server has TCP connections enabled (either following this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191294.aspx or by specifying `/tcpenabled=1` flag to the installer).
2. Make sure you have remote access enabled (`sp_configure N'remote access',N'1'`)
3. Make sure the firewall is configured to let you through or just disable it (**only** do so if the SQL Server is installed in a disposable VM): `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`

I wrote a [blog post](https://bazzilic.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/guide-to-quick-command-line-installation-of-sql-server-20142016-on-a-core-server/) on how to install SQL Server properly.